# como puedo cerrar searchview fuera del onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: lista, imagen, android-fragment, android-recyclerview, searchview

Como puedo cerrar searchview fuera del onCreateOptionsMenu, ejemplo al presionar algún chip (para escoger un genero) quiero que el buscador este cerrado, lo que sucede es que cuando doy buscar se queda abierto aunque cambie de genero!!! Me explico mejor tengo en la barra de titulo un searchview, debajo un ChipGroup con géneros debajo un recyclerview con una lista de películas y debajo un menú de navegación entre fragmentos, esto es a modo general, por otro lado tengo 3 fragmentos(Películas Novelas y Series) y en cada fragmento un grupo de chips con sus respectivos géneros. Cuando doy clic en un chip me actualiza la lista pero cuando doy buscar si ya estaba abierto el buscador no me busca en ese genero, no siendo así si esta cerrado busca perfectamente por eso quiero que al presionar un genero cierre el buscador si esta abierto

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.superior,menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.new_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        listvideotemporal.addAll(listvideoseleccionada);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Buscar película...");

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String textoaFiltrar) {
                filtarlista(textoaFiltrar);
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```